# Docker private registry with multiple registry urls using nginx

Tags: nginx, docker, docker-registry

I currently have systems that are using a private Docker registry going through nginx, however I want to change the registry to a new location (with a new hostname).

Is it possible to use nginx to rewrite/redirect the url to the new registry.

E.g.

I have a registry `registry-old.domain.com`, and I have a new one `registry-new.domain.com`. I want to be able to continue using `docker pull registry-old.domain.com`, but for it to actually go to the new registry `registry-new.domain.com`.

I'm not sure if this is possible due to the fact that you have to tag the image with the registry url.

This is my nginx config currently:

```
# New config to cover old and new domain
# Works for new, but not for the old domain
server {
  server_name registry-old.domain.com registry-new.domain.com;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
    proxy_set_header Host registry-new.domain.com; # Also tried $host
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  }
}

# Original working registry
#server {
#  server_name registry-old.domain.com;
#
#  location / {
#    proxy_pass http://oldRegistry:5000;
#    proxy_set_header Host $host;
#    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
#  }
#}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that but if you're using TLS you must have a wildcard TLS certificate with `*.domain.com` as common name or `DNS:*.domain.com` in the Subject Alternative Name.

Comment: Do you know how I can do this, as it doesn't seem to just work (ignoring TLS)? I have also tried forcing the host name in the proxy.

Comment: See the example config at:
https://github.com/docker/distribution/tree/master/contrib/compose/nginx

I would add to that example configuration the following to enable keepalives:

```proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Connection "";```